# sql query to get the previous row value of one column to be inserted as 2nd row value of another column

Tags: php, sql

my table structure is like this

```
username   Period  Numberproduced  stockonhand   totalavailableforsale  actualsale  Inventoryremaining

pranab      1       100               2000           2100                 2000        100
pranab      2       200               100             300                  500         0
pranab      3       400               0               400                  100        300 
pranab      4       500               300             800                  400        400
```

stockinhand of period-1 is always constant=2000.

stockinhand of period-2 is= inventoryremaining of period-1 & so on

can u please tell the query to execute this.

Comment: question is way too unclear for my taste

Comment: stockinhand of period-1 is always constant=2000.

stockinhand of period-2 is= inventoryremaining of period-1 & so on

Comment: which rdbms do you use?

Comment: Mysql & xamp server

Answer (score 0):

If `Period` field is unique and increment, then this solution should work:

```
SELECT
    A.*
    , [stockinhand] = IIF(A.[Period] = 1, 2000, B.[inventoryremaining])
FROM
    [Table] AS A
        CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM
        [Table] AS B
    WHERE
        A.[Period] > B.[Period]
    ORDER BY
        B.[Period] DESC
    ) AS B
```

also note, that if you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, `LAG` or `LEAD` clause will simplify the solution.

Comment: Username filed is uique

Comment: Username is same for all period

Comment: User has to enter period, number produced& actual sale is declared by admin.  Based on this calculation is dobe

Comment: then it is not unique. Unique means that it has no duplicates. you have 4 duplicate here.

Answer (score 0):

If `period` is sequential (no gaps) use -

```
select  t.*
       ,coalesce
        (
           (select      Inventoryremaining 
            from        mytable as t2 
            where       t2.period = t.period - 1
            )
           ,2000
        )  as stockonhand   

from    mytable t
```

else use -

```
select  t.*
       ,coalesce
        (
           (select      Inventoryremaining 
            from        mytable as t2 
            where       t2.period < t.period 
            order by    t2.period 
            desc        limit 1
            )
           ,2000
        )  as stockonhand   

from    mytable t
```

Comment: not working..please recheck the error message is -   Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row in C:\xampp\htdocs\lampson\calculation.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lampson\calculation.php(73): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lampson\calculation.php on line 73

Comment: According to the error only a single row is expected but due to your request all rows are returned